# Adding dynamic content in to jquery mobile applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have an ajax call shown below and am really unsure on the best way to inject my server side content into the page.

If I just respond to the same page in a table it works fine. If I attempt to change page and inject content it fails.

I have read extensively about, pagecreate, pagecontainer, load, pageinit, pagebeforecreate, pageaftercreate and am unsure if I need to hook into any of these.

Is it possible to generate complete pages of content? or do I need to have a receiving page set up and inject in to that. I am interested in the correct practice and events that most hook onto to render server content.

In addition I am using phonegap as a wrapper can I inject html and still get accepted by the app store or does it have to be JSONP.

I am failing to understand if I can navigate to a new page and upon arriving to this page have ajax content load. I hope this makes sense.

My ajax call below works and I get the response text I just do not know where to put it. Currently I am trying to change page and inject into a table on the navigated to page- this is not working.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#pageone', function(){  
        $(document).on('click', '#lecreate', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();// catch the form's submit event
           var mystring = JSON.stringify(league);

                    $.ajax({url: 'testjson.php',
                        data: {mydata : mystring},
                        type: 'post',                   
                        async: 'true',
                        //dataType: 'jsonp',//sending array not json 
                        beforeSend: function() {

                            $.mobile.loading( 'show', 
                            {text: 'Loading',
                              textVisible:true,
                                theme: 'b',
                                textonly: false

                            }) 
                        },
                        complete: function(data) {

                             $.mobile.loading( 'hide');
                              console.log(data);
                              $.mobile.changePage("#pagethree"); 
                                $('#table10').html(data);
                        },
                        success: function (data) {



                        },
                        error: function (request,error) {
                            // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
                            alert('Network error ');
                        }


                    });                   

        });    
});
```

Currently my content being returned is HTML.

Comment: You can inject a whole page. Just make sure to use unique IDs and append it to the body. Finally call the pageconatainer change method to navigate to the new page; http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change

Comment: @ezanker thanks for your response. I have tried using this but I finding the documentation confusing. I do not get where I would use this. When I am dealing with the server response do I run the change page container then place my html into the new page container (what does it do?). Do you have a really simplified example of its use. Is this a page that I already have made in my index? and will it have all the libraries available to it. I do not get why I can `$('body').html(server response)` fails, bur when I .html(#table1)' it was put in the page.

Comment: thanks @ezanker i have this working I call pageContainer and change to page three complete option and then .html() in my success callback. However append does not work. Would this be a reasonable way to do it? . Thanks for your help with the page container

Comment: If you want to add a whole page, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yx02swts/

Comment: thank you that little code snippet is so useful. Do you use page create in a similar way to document ready? . Looks incredibly simple and logical now I have seen it. I do not see why JQM dont put examples like that in the docs and let the end user build on them to create the complicated examples. There are not many basic (useful basic) examples in the docs. Makes it difficult for the none technical (definition aware) users. Thanks very much for taking the time to make that.

Comment: You are welcome. pagecreate and the othe page and pagecontainer events are used instead of document ready. That way you know that not only is the document ready, but that the jQM widgets have been created/initialized.